# Swapping axes plotting Scatter chart in VBA

Tags: excel, charts, vba

Using the following code I get the graph I want exactly as I want it except that it plots the axes the wrong way round. How do I get it to change the X data to Y data and vice versa?

```
    Sub AddChartObject()


    Set cht = ActiveChart
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("AB30:AD40")



    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=rng.Left, Width:=rng.Width, Top:=rng.Top, Height:=rng.Height)
     '(Left:=100, Width:=375, Top:=75, Height:=225)
        .Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines

        .Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("O30:O40,N30:N40")


    End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `XValues` and `Values` independently, after you add the data to the chart.

```
Dim srs as Series

With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=rng.Left, Width:=rng.Width, Top:=rng.Top, Height:=rng.Height)
 '(Left:=100, Width:=375, Top:=75, Height:=225)
    .Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines

    '.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("O30:O40,N30:N40")
    Set srs = .Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    srs.Name = "The series name" '<-- edit as needed
    srs.XValues = Range("O30:O40")
    srs.Values = Range("N30:N40")

End With
```

If that doesn't do it, then just flip the Values/xValues like:

```
    srs.XValues = Range("N30:N40")
    srs.Values = Range("O30:O40")
```

One of these methods will do it for you.

Comment: Perfect! Works exactly as needed. Thank you.

Comment: Excellent. Yes it's just a matter of overriding the default assumptions that Excel uses when you "Insert Chart" from the ribbon/menu.